Set RigidBody2D scale in Godot 4.2.1
I have a 2d ragdoll for a player and im trying to make it when the player is facing the opposite way, when they ragdoll, they don't just sparaticly spin around, I tried setting the parent Node2D to a negative scale and applying that scale to the physics server but when I rag doll it still spins out of controll

func flip(dir):
    ragdollFunc(false,"idle")
    scale.x = dir
    for limb in UFunc.get_all_children(self,"RigidBody2D"):
        PhysicsServer2D.body_set_state(
            limb.get_rid(),
            PhysicsServer2D.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM,
            Transform2D.IDENTITY.translated(scale)
            #Transform2D.IDENTITY.translated(limb.global_position)
            )
    ragdollFunc(true,"idle")

func ragdollFunc(_bool,animName,specific:=""):
    $Animation.stop()
    var all = UFunc.get_all_children(self)
    
    for body in all:
        for body2 in all:
            if body.is_class("RigidBody2D") && body2.is_class("RigidBody2D"):
                body.add_collision_exception_with(body2)
        if body.is_class("RigidBody2D"):
            #body.add_collision_exception_with(self)
            body.freeze = !_bool
    
    if _bool == false:
        $Animation.play(animName)
    
    for limb in UFunc.get_all_children(self,"RigidBody2D"):
        PhysicsServer2D.body_set_state(
            limb.get_rid(),
            PhysicsServer2D.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM,
            Transform2D.IDENTITY.translated(limb.global_position)
            )
    for limb in UFunc.get_all_children(self,"RigidBody2D"):
        PhysicsServer2D.body_set_state(
            limb.get_rid(),
            PhysicsServer2D.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM,
            Transform2D.IDENTITY.translated(scale)
            #Transform2D.IDENTITY.translated(limb.global_position)
            )
        


I tried manually setting the position, setting the obj physicsserver2d property to the rigidbodys scale, and the rigid body global position

It's not a good idea to scale a physics object or it's parent node, rather separate out your visuals like skins, sprites, etc and flip them. In your case I see that would be difficult so maybe just flip the individual sprites and then change the positions of the physics object to their mirrored side, Also try to pin point your error since usually the longer the question the less chance someone solves it :)

that's what I was afraid of, ill just flip the sprites and rearrange the pinpoint position & rigid body, I just didn't know if it was possible to just flip it and apply it to the physics server. Thank you
